# A replicated SQL Server stored procedure returns different results

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I had created a new stored procedure from an existing one. all I did was copy the old one and changed the name.

Now when i run both in the query analyzer, i get data from the original but the new one does not return any data.

It could be with permissions but both are set to public. Any thoughts?

Comment: Are you getting any data when you run the script inside the stored procedure directly?

Comment: What is the new proc's owner? And is the new proc in the same schema as the original? And have you looked at the query execution plan for each?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating script and re-replicating the sp worked. it could have been the proc's owner or permissions related. dont feel like debugging any more after I got that working.

Answer (score 1):

check ansi-nulls value? they can casuse a headach. hard to tell without seeing the code but as a general debug rule; break it apart into its basic queryies and see where the issue is introduced or where it starts to diferentiate from results of the original stored sprocedure

Answer (score 1):

Sorry if my question appears naïve, but... how did you actually make the copy?

I have only used SSMS to work with DBs so far and am oblivious of other interactive tools, if there are any. As to SSMS, a mere replicating is often done in this scenario: `sp_helptext [proc name]`, then copying the output into a new query window, changing the name and voila (i.e. 'executing the script'). The permissions are peeked at in the original proc's properties and usually added using the same or a new script.

It seems so trivial that I feel a bit guilty to put it here. Anyway, that method has never failed me so far. What is yours then?

Sorry, this of course doesn't answer your particular problem with the already copied SP. I just thought maybe you wanted some help in the more fundamental problem of its replicating.

Comment: I have generated scripts for that particular stored procedure and executed it back after editing the name of the proc. Very much the same as what you have described. This could have been a permissions issue but i have replicated them as well. Unfortunately(or fortunately) once i recreated the proc the second time, it worked fine and i did not bother to go back to review the original.